# Soundcloud Custom Player - IOS 5 Returning Intermittant NaN Value for onMediabuffering event

Tags: soundcloud

I've come across a problem with the soundcloud custom player in Safari IOS 5 in that the Play Bar Indicator, Track Buffer Bar Indicator and Seek function stops working correctly.

To recreate the problem, use the included example red skin, and keep selecting between two tracks. Eventually the buffer indicator will not reset to the beginning and the player indicator will either not show or get stuck in one position. Because of this the track seek function just keeps restarting the track as it's based on the indicators position values.

I have traced the problem down to the onMediabuffering event returning a value of NaN rather than a percentage (line 479 sc-player.js)  But do not know what is causing this? Or how to fix it. This problem does not occur in Safari IOS 4 or any Desktop browsers.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or any solutions to the problem?